# .text() immediately being processed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not know what title to give so please I do apologize, i'm just getting curious why in the code below, the text is getting changed before it even fades out even if i've put it after a fade.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('busy');
    $(this).parent().find('button').attr('disabled',true);
    $(this).parent().find("button:not('.busy')").fadeOut(500);
    $('p').text('Processing..').fadeIn(500).trigger('sfsfsf','wala');
});
$('p').on('sfsfsf',function(e,data){
    //this line below
    $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(500).text('Complete!');
    $(this).fadeIn(500,function(){
        $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v4nwQ/

Why is that so, and how do i Fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Because [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) returns immediately before the animation has complete; `text()` then gets processed straight away. You should instead change the text in the `fadeOut()` callback;

```
$(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function () {
    $(this).text('Complete!');
});
```

Unrelated, but something to note; you should look at caching the result of `$(this)`; you're calling it a lot.

```
$('p').on('sfsfsf',function(e,data){
    var self = $(this);

    self.delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function () {
        self.text('Complete!');
    });

    self.fadeIn(500,function(){
        self.delay(500).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice, now I understand. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. All functions in a chain execute immediately. If you want something to execute after an animation, you use the callback parameter that all animations include.

And delay *only* delays animations! It has no effect on things that are not animations. So:

```
$(this).fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).text('Complete!'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().find("button:not('.busy')").fadeOut(500, function() {
$('p').text('Processing..').fadeIn(500).trigger('sfsfsf','wala');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the text in the call back funciton of the fade like you're doing it in the last few lines:

```
$(this).fadeIn(500,function(){
        $(this).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
    });
```

otherwise the text change is executed immediately